# Using Javascript Collections with Conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, collections

I am trying to set a 'readonly' attribute on elements based if their text content meets a certain condition. The condition, in particular, is that the elements must contain either the text "Disbursed" or "Pending Disbursement". I have encountered two problems that I can't seems to get over for a few hours;

1. I am unable to select elements that contain the text/phrase "Pending Disbursement". Could the problem be the space between "Pending" and "Disbursed"? Because I'm able to select all elements containing the text "Disbursed".
2. How do I make all elements of the class 'req-amount-input' uneditable (readonly) if the criteria above is met (text content of element to contain the word 'Disbursed' or the phrase 'Pending Disbursement')?

Here's what I've come up with so far.

```
    var statusClassCollection = document.getElementsByClassName('req-status');
    var textContent_criteria = ['Disbursed', 'Pending Disbursement'];
    var approvedReqsCollection = Array.prototype.filter.call(
        statusClassCollection,
        ({
            textContent
        }) => textContent_criteria.includes(textContent)
    );

    for (j = 0; j < approvedReqsCollection.length; j++) {

        var amountsClassCollection = document.getElementsByClassName("req-amount-input");
        for (i = 0; i < amountsClassCollection.length; i++) {

            amountsClassCollection[i].readonly = true;
            amountsClassCollection[i].editReqAmount = function() {
                return false;
            };

        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your HTML for the class ```req-status``` element?

Comment: @ikhvjs 

`<span class="btn btn-sm btn-success req-status"><?php echo $row["disb_status"]; ?><i class="bi bi-check-all"></i></span>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the example. I guess you want to set all the input to readOnly if there is any `Disbursed` or `Pending Disbursement` span element.

```js
const statusClassCollection = document.getElementsByClassName("req-status");
const criteria = ["Disbursed", "Pending Disbursement"];

let isCriteriaMatched = false;

for (let i = 0; i < statusClassCollection.length; i++) {
  if (criteria.includes(statusClassCollection[i].textContent)) {
    isCriteriaMatched = true;
    break;
  }
}

if (isCriteriaMatched) {
  const amountsClassCollection =
    document.getElementsByClassName("req-amount-input");
  for (let i = 0; i < amountsClassCollection.length; i++) {
    amountsClassCollection[i].readOnly = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <span class="btn btn-sm btn-success req-status"
        >Disbursed<i class="bi bi-check-all"></i
      ></span>
      <span class="btn btn-sm btn-success req-status"
        >Pending Disbursement<i class="bi bi-check-all"></i
      ></span>
      <span class="btn btn-sm btn-success req-status"
        >Pending Disbursement<i class="bi bi-check-all"></i
      ></span>
      <span class="btn btn-sm btn-success req-status"
        >Disbursed<i class="bi bi-check-all"></i
      ></span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input class="req-amount-input" type="text" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```